# How many GPIOs does Raspberry Pi A+ really have?

Tags: raspberry-pi

Could someone clarify for me why official documentation of RPI A+ says that it has 40 GPIOs while other sources, such as forums, online courses, and others say that it has 54 GPIOs? What is each one talking about? Is there a difference in types of GPIOs that each source is referring to?

**RPI Tutorial by University of Cambridge**
https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/os/ok01.html :
"There are **54 GPIO pins**, so we need 6 sets of 4 bytes, which is 24 bytes in total."

**Adafruit Website RPI specs**
https://www.adafruit.com/product/2266 : "It's still compatible with all Pi operating systems and software, and has the exact same **40 pin GPIO** connector and camera/display sockets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BCM2835/BCM2835 micro-processor have 54 general-purpose I/O (GPIO) lines in total. This what RPI Tutorial by University of Cambridge is claiming but out of these 54 GPIO lines only **28** general-purpose I/O (GPIO) come on the external J8 header which can easily be interfaced with outside world. 12 pin are used as power pins +3.3V (2), +5V (2) and GND (8).

Comment: Does that mean we do not have physical access to 14 of the 54 GPIO pins via the RPI?

Comment: They are routed to DSI and camera connector.